# how to fix opening/reading json file using python

Tags: python

i'm reading a json file in python which has huge amount of imported goods data

```
import json

with open("data.json") as f:
data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

but it displays this error

```
File "C:\Users\ALAA\Desktop\hello\dictionary.py", line 4
    data = json.load(f)
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: As the error message says, you are expected to indent the block of a ``with`` statement. A single space, ideally four of them, before `data` will do.

Comment: Your new error means that there is no file named 'data.json' in the folder your code is running from: C:\Users\ALAA\Desktop\hello\

Comment: People can only answer one question, and they cannot guess further problems you encounter. Please do not change the topic of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't well indented,

Try this:

```py
import json

with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

Comment: did you add 4 space or tabulation before `data = json.load(f)` ??

Comment: yes i did now i got new error which i mentioned above

Comment: is your file `data.json` in the same directory as your python file, or try using a full path

Comment: yah it works now when i used python shell , but it did not work when i used atom